Extensive regression statistics with scipy and sklearn
I'm working on calculating various linear regression metrics, including R^2, Pearson, Spearman, and Kendall coefficients, and also estimating MSE (Mean Squared Error) and MUE (Mean Absolute Error). I've implemented most of the equations manually but am unsure about their correctness and the proper usage of Python modules. I'm particularly concerned about the error estimation for these metrics.
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import kendalltau, linregress, t, pearsonr, spearmanr, rankdata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

# Calculate Kendall coefficient
kendall_coefficient, p_value_kendall = kendalltau(values_array, ordered_values_array)

# Calculate Pearson coefficient
pearson_coefficient, p_value_pearson = pearsonr(values_array, ordered_values_array)

# Calculate Spearman coefficient
spearman_coefficient, p_value_spearman = spearmanr(values_array, ordered_values_array)

# MSE and MUE
mse = mean_squared_error(values_array, ordered_values_array)
mue = mean_absolute_error(values_array, ordered_values_array)

# Perform linear regression
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value_regression, std_err = linregress(ordered_values_array, values_array)

# Calculate R-squared
r_squared = r_value ** 2
print(r_squared)

# Calculate standard error of the slope and intercept
alpha = 0.05
df = len(ordered_values_array) - 2
t_value = t.ppf(1 - alpha / 2, df)

stderr_slope = std_err
stderr_intercept = stderr_slope * np.sqrt(np.mean(ordered_values_array ** 2))

# Calculate confidence intervals for the slope and intercept
slope_ci = (slope - t_value * stderr_slope, slope + t_value * stderr_slope)
intercept_ci = (intercept - t_value * stderr_intercept, intercept + t_value * stderr_intercept)

# Calculate errors for MSE and MUE
mse_error = mse * np.sqrt(2 / len(values_array))
mue_error = mue * np.sqrt(2 / len(values_array))

# Analytical calculations
# Pearson's r
x_mean = np.mean(values_array)
y_mean = np.mean(values_array)
pearson_numerator = np.sum((values_array - x_mean) * (values_array - y_mean))
pearson_denominator = np.sqrt(np.sum((values_array - x_mean) ** 2) * np.sum((ordered_values_array - y_mean) ** 2))
pearson_r_manual = pearson_numerator / pearson_denominator
pearson_se = np.sqrt((1 - pearson_r_manual ** 2) / (len(values_array) - 2))

# Kendall's tau
concordant = discordant = 0
for i in range(len(values_array)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(values_array)):
        if (values_array[i] - values_array[j]) * (ordered_values_array[i] - ordered_values_array[j]) > 0:
            concordant += 1
        elif (values_array[i] - values_array[j]) * (ordered_values_array[i] - ordered_values_array[j]) < 0:
            discordant += 1
kendall_tau_manual = (concordant - discordant) / (0.5 * len(values_array) * (len(values_array) - 1))
kendall_se = np.sqrt((2 * (2 * len(values_array) + 5)) / (9 * len(values_array) * (len(values_array) - 1)))

# Spearman's rho
rank_exp = rankdatavalues_array)
rank_ordered = rankdata(ordered_values_array)
d = rank_exp - rank_ordered
spearman_rho_manual = 1 - (6 * np.sum(d ** 2)) / (len(values_array) * (len(values_array) ** 2 - 1))

# Bootstrap for Spearman's rho standard error
def bootstrap_spearman(x, y, n_bootstraps=100):
    bootstrapped_rhos = []
    for _ in range(n_bootstraps):
        indices = np.random.choice(range(len(x)), len(x), replace=True)
        boot_x = x[indices]
        boot_y = y[indices]
        bootstrapped_rhos.append(spearmanr(boot_x, boot_y)[0])
    return np.std(bootstrapped_rhos)

spearman_se = bootstrap_spearman(values_array, ordered_values_array)



My questions are related to some aspects, related to the two Python modules used:

Are the methods used to calculate the errors for MSE and MUE accurate? Specifically, is using np.sqrt(2 / len(values_array)) appropriate?

Are those manual implementations for Pearson's

r, Kendall's

τ, and Spearman's

ρ correct? I am particularly unsure about the calculation of standard errors.

Does this bootstrap procedure for estimating Spearman's standard error seem appropriate? Is there a more reliable method?

Are the calculations for confidence intervals for the slope and intercept correct?


Any insights or corrections would be greatly appreciated!
Additionally, to test the code, it would be helpful to have a verified dataset with already calculated regression coefficients.

Why do you use the abbreviation MUE for Mean Absolute Error? I've never seen that abbreviation before.

@NickODell, it should be Mean Unsigned Error. Just a matter of words.

Thanks. Looking at it now. I've found a counter-example for Pearson: values_array = np.random.rand(100); ordered_values_array = np.random.rand(100) reports a correlation near 1, where sklearn reports a value near 0. The two random samples are uncorrelated, so it should be near 0.

@NickODell, do you mean it should be better to use the automatic equations and not those manual?

I just mean there's a bug in your manual calculation. Is it better to do it manually, or use a library for it? I don't know. It depends on the application. You haven't explained why you're implementing this manually, so I just assumed you had a good reason.

This question might get more answers on https://codereview.stackexchange.com?
